# How to use setParameter (JPQL Namedquery) with multiple parameters

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have a JPQL NamedQuery with several parameters
With one parameter executing would look like

```
private String a; //Getter setter for a
em.createNamedQuery("NamedQueryName").setParameter("param", a)
```

How can I do that with more that One parameter ?

Comment: `EntityManager#createNamedQuery` follows the builder pattern. `setParameter` returns the `TypedQuery` object so you can simply chain the `setParameter` calls. `setParameter().setParameter()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below solution
replace `<Entityname>` with entity name and `<namedQuery>` with the named Query

```
 Query query = createNamedQuery("<Entityname>.<namedQuery>");
 query.setParameter("column1", value1);
 query.setParameter("column2", value2);
 query.setParameter("column3", value3);
 query.getSingleResult()
```